# Open link in different browser using electron-shell and ipcMain

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

Hi :] due to some digital certification policies in my application so I depend on the user to register a form from through the browser. I am having to implement this solution because the electron does not support extensions from Mozilla Firefox and I needed it exactly because in order for the user to send the form he must authenticate some documents about the company's ownership digitally and for this, he must select his digital certificate by the extension I mentioned above.

I've tried to run some examples present in documentation of the electron-shell but without success

My main.js

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
var Menu = require('menu');
var fs = require('fs');
var shell = require('shell');
var mainWindow = null;

require("babel-register")();

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('ready', function() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    autoHideMenuBar: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false
    },
    width: 1200,
        height: 750
  });

var template = [
  require("./server").start()
  .then((app) => {
    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');
  }).catch((err) => {

  });

  mainWindow.openDevTools();
  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
});

ipcMain.on('loadGH', (event, arg) => {
    shell.openExternal(arg);
});
```

My front-end plugins.

```
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.9.1/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

My instantiate the ICP module in head html

```
<script>
   const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
</script>
```

Is my button which should open the Mozilla Firefox

```
<a class="indigo white-text btn" onclick="ipc.send('loadGH','http://google.com');"><i class="material-icons left">undo</i>OPEN BROWSER</a>
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: require is different in [electron shell docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/shell.md):
`const {shell} = require('electron')` (or `electron.shell` in your case). That may make difference